# My enums should be accepted as int?

Tags: c#

I have this filetypeenum:

```
public enum FileType : int
{
    jpeg = 0,
    png = 1,
}
```

why does it `say == cant be applied to int type and FileType` when i try to compare:

```
int type = 1;
if( type == FileType.jpeg)
```

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the conversion is not implicit.  C# will not automatically convert between enum types and the enum base type because in many situations this can cause behavior not expected by the programmer.

Try this instead:

```
if ((FileType)type == FileType.jpeg)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try casting it

```
if((FileType)type == FileType.jpeg)
```

or

```
if(type == (int)FileType.jpeg)
```

Comment: *"FileType is an int but an int is not a FileType."* Wrong. The types are both compatible with each other, and they can both be casted to each other. The trick is that neither conversion is implicit. (Note that, even though the syntax for declaring enums with specific base types resembles declaring the supertype of a new type, enums are a special case. Enum values essentially *are* "instances" of the enum's base type, with some language and runtime support that prevents you from doing things you didn't mean to.)